# appended ahref does not start function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have the following situation and i dont really have a clou why it does not fire:

```
$('.tab3').click(function() {
               //console.log("test");
               $('.coda-nav').append('<a href="#" style="position: relative;" id="ref1">blabla</a>');
               $('.coda-nav').append('<a href="#" style="position: relative;" id="ref2">blabla</a>');
               $('.coda-nav').append('<a href="#" style="position: relative;" id="ref3">blabla</a>');
            });
```

this works pretty well. if i click on tab3 it appends 3 links! then:

```
$('#ref2').click(function() {
        console.log("test");
    });
```

pls tell me why nothing happened onclick at ref2!

thanks ted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Your `click` handler does not get attached to the newly created `<a>`. You need `On` to attach it on the fly.

So that would become:

```
$(".coda-nav").on("click", "#ref2", function() {
    console.log("test");
});
```

Comment: okay thanks, this worked for me! but really i will never get it why my snippet does not work! would it work with a timeout? it would be awesome if someone could explain me why it does not get attached!

Comment: Well, to put it simply. When your page loads, you attach your click (using  `.click()`) handler to all elements matching `#ref2`. However, there are no elements with that `#ref2` yet, so nothing happens. Then you add the anchor with the id `ref2`, but the `click()` handler doesnt do anything anymore. With `.on()` however, it attaches the handler to all current and *future*  elements that match the selector, thus it works.

Answer (score 3):

Because the anchors are added *after* the `click` event is bound, i.e. elements do not exist when you bind the event.

You can use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to fix it:

```
$(".coda-nav").on("click", "#ref2", function() {
    console.log("test");
});
```